# Django - change temporary path while uploading files

Tags: python, django

By default Django stores all its temp files in "/tmp" when files are uploaded.
I tried to change the FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR in settings.py to give a custom path. But Django fails to take the new path.

File size > 10MB

Tried the following properties in settings.py

```
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS = (
    'django.core.files.uploadhandler.MemoryFileUploadHandler',
    'django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler',
)
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 2621440
FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR = "/datadrive/test"
MEDIA_ROOT = '/datadrive/test'
SESSION_FILE_PATH = '/datadrive/test'
FILE_UPLOAD_DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS = 0o644
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSION = 0o644
```

Comment: You do know that that directory is only used for files with size greater than `FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE` and files smaller than that are stored in memory right?

Comment: Yes. Even for files with size >2.5 MB it's storing the files in /tmp and not in the FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR